How to solve error on oracle-debezium llowing error: java.sql.SQLExcep ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [krvrdccs10]?
I'm trying to enable CDC (Debezium) in oracle 18c database ? I am getting the following error:
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor-java \n\tat java.base/java.lang. Thread.run(Thread-java:829) \nCaused by: java.sql.SQLExcep ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [krvrdccs10], [], [], [], [, [, [, [], 0, ll, LAn n\tat
That's my connector config:
{ "connector.class": "io.debezium. connector.oracle.OracleConnector", "topic.creation.default.partitions": 1, "tasks.max": 1, "log.mining.strategy": "online_catalog" , "topic.prefix": "pdtfornec", "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "schemahistory", "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": 1, "database.dbname": "dbname", "database.user": "C##PDDBZUSER", "database.pdb.name": "fornecnp", "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "host:9092", "database.port": "1521" "topic.creation.enable": true, "database.hostname": "hostname", "database.password": "password", "name": "name", "table.include.list": "table1,table2", "database, include.list": "table" "Log.mining.query filter mode": "in" "snapshot.mode": "no _data" }
I'm searching for information to understand the possible reasons of this error.
